# Left-aligned display math mode

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, tex-core, plain-tex

How could one achieve, as primitively as possible, left-aligned display math so that `\abovedisplayshortskip` would still work as intended?

It is my understanding that one can achieve left-alignment via an immediate `\halign` inside display math mode, but this makes (again, in my understanding) it occupy the whole width of the display, and hence makes it impossible for there to be `\abovedisplayshortskip` (or `\belowditto`).

Here is what I have now:

```
Some text $$\displaylines{\kern2\parindent % i.e. \halign
  a + b = c
\hfill}$$ and so continues the paragraph. Until
\bye
```

Comment: I guess you don't mention `fleqn` class option for some reason? ah yes I see from the sources that it sets `\abovedisplayshortskip` to be as `\abovedisplayskip` for `eqnarray` environment, but you could patch that.

Comment: @jfbu - I believe the OP is looking for a PlainTeX rather than a LaTeX solution.

Comment: @Mico silly me, thanks for pointing that out. Maybe then looking at `fleqn.clo` will provide inspiration for a Plain TeX approach.

Comment: An `\halign` would only take up the full width if you explicitly told it to do so.  So the `\begindisplay` and `\enddisplay` macros from Appendix E of the TeXbook should work properly with `\abovedisplayskip`.

Comment: @Thruston: Oh! Right you are! It is the `\displaylines` which makes it `\displaywidth` wide (actually, the **inside** of it, by the looks of it). I wonder if `\displayindent` could be used for the indenting.

Comment: @Thruston: Oh, and thank you for the reference to appendix E. Although I must say I have a little trouble understanding what is going on in the definitions of `\begindisplay`/`\startdisplay`.

Comment: @jfbu: Thanks for the reference to `fleqn.clo`, but I would like to try and avoid reading any LaTeX sources if at all possible, because every time I've tried to do that, this weird salty watery stuff starts coming out of my eyes.

Comment: @morbusg After some closer reading of Appx E, I notice that the definition there has (in effect) `$$\halign{...}$$` which makes an "alignment display" which is formatted differently... As p.190 makes clear alignment displays always get `\abovedisplayskip` and never `\abovedisplayshortskip`.  So you might want to experiment with wrapping the halign in a vbox and adjusting hsize.

Comment: It's simple: when using left aligned displays, you shouldn't even think to `\abovedisplayshortskip`.

Comment: @egreg: depends on the amount of indent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first thought (you didn't wait long enough to get my answer) was to set the math left aligned in an `\hbox` that was shorter than the `\displaywidth` by twice the indentation value:

```
\newdimen\mydisplayboxwidth
\newdimen\mydisplayindent
\mydisplayindent 2\parindent % 
\noindent OK:
$$\mydisplayboxwidth\displaywidth
  \advance\mydisplayboxwidth-2\mydisplayindent
  \hbox to \mydisplayboxwidth
    {$\mathsurround0pt \displaystyle a + b = c$\hss}
\eqno(1)$$
and so continues the paragraph.
\bye
```

Comment: Oh, it can be that straight-forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No takers? I'm sorry I'm doing the unthinkable and answering my own question.

Thanks to @Thruston for finding the relevant part from The TeXbook (p. 190):

> TeX also allows “alignment displays”, which are not processed in math mode because they contain no formulas at the outer level.  An alignment display is created by commands of the general form
>
> ```
> $$<assignments>\halign{<alignment>}<assignments>$$
> ```
>
> where the `<assignments>` are optional things like parameter changes that do not produce any math lists.  In such displays, the `\halign` is processed exactly as if it had appeared in vertical mode, and it will construct a vertical list `v` as usual, except that **each row of the alignment will be shifted by the `\displayindent`**.  After the alignment and the closing assignments have been processed, TeX will put a `\predisplaypenalty` item and some `\abovedisplayskip` glue on the main vertical list, followed by `v`, followed by `\postdisplaypenalty` item and `\belowdisplayskip` glue.

(Emphasis mine.)

So building on this knowledge, one could do something like the following for `\displaylines`-like command with indenting (I've left out all the other things it's doing):

```
\everydisplay={\displayindent=3\parindent}

\def\indentlines#1{
  \halign{
    \mathsurround=0pt
    $\displaystyle ##\hfil$\crcr
    \noalign{
      \ifdim\predisplaysize<\displayindent
        \kern-\abovedisplayskip\vskip\abovedisplayshortskip
      \fi}
    #1\crcr}}

\hsize=38em
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie
consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan
et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis
dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.$$
  \indentlines{ a + b = c. }
$$ Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\bye
```

For some reason the `\displayindent` needs to be set inside display math mode and not outside.